# Logging on as root without winbind timeouts

Tags: login, pam, winbind

How can I set up my Linux box so that, if the Active Directory domain controller is down, I can still log in as root, without any timeouts or delays?

Following the example of most of the documentation out there, I've listed `pam_winbind.so` before `pam_unix.so` in my `/etc/pam.d` configurations.  I believe that this is the cause of the problem.  I remember seeing alternate `/etc/pam.d` setups that change the order and maybe add either `pam_localuser` or `pam_succeed_if` (to see if the uid is less than 500), but I can't find any specifics now (and I'm not enough of an expert in PAM to quickly and easily come up with a robust configuration on my own).

What is the recommended setup for PAM with Winbind to avoid timeouts and delays if Active Directory is unavailable?

Comment: You are right, for what you want pam_unix.so should be placed before pam_winbind.so. But try to put sufficiant keyword in pam_unix.so line, so it would log in right away, without checking winbind.

Answer (score 4):

Not only do you generally want `pam_unix` first, but when you fire up any session, pam will enumerate the groups you belong to using `initgroups(3)`, which will go through all `group` backends defined in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

There are a few reasons for this behaviour, mostly technical limitations around separation of concerns, but in short this allows you to specify in `/etc/groups` that an LDAP user belongs to `wheel` to allow it to `sudo` (random example).

This leads to stories about `root` login being broken or very slow on hosts with remote directory servers, even when the user is defined locally. Those stories are true, but most often due to incorrect configuration.

If you use `winbind`, you can define users for which groups will not be looked for through `winbind`. The appropriate option is `winbind initgroups blacklist` (global) in `smb.conf`. It was introduced in 2007 through http://git.samba.org/?p=samba.git;a=commitdiff;h=7399ab779d7100059475ed196e6e4435b2b33bbd

Note that the default value contains `root`, so you probably don't need to overwrite it.

**For visitors:**

If you use `nss_ldap`, `ldap.conf` offers a similar `nss_initgroups_ignoreusers`. See `nss_ldap(5)`.